# How to specify "any element" in a sequence

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

Could someone tell me how to specify in an XSD, that an element can contain any number of arbitrary elements?  For exmaple, if I have

```
<person>
    <name>Foo</name>
</person>
```

I would like to allow any element after the "`<name>`" element.

```
<person>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <gender>male</gender>
</person>

<person>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <address>west of here</address>
</person>

<person>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <address>west of here</address>
    <spooge>something else</spooge>
</person>
```

That is, the name element is required, but after that, you can add any arbitrary element with any type.  So if this is the XSD element to describe the `<person>` element, what would go after the "`<xs:element name='name' .../>`"

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use [`xsd:any`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Wildcard_details):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:any processContents="skip" namespace="##any"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Pay particular attention to the possible values for `processContent`:**

- **skip**: Allow any element, and ignore any definition for the element.
- **lax**: Allow any element, but validate the element if any definition is found for it.
- **strict**: Allow any element, but require that it have a definition and be valid per that definition.

Comment: Excellent!  lax is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

The solution for me was :

```
<xs:complexType name="dataType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

> My IDE (PHPStorm) run error with `xs:any` but `xs:anyAttribute` is supported